# Does a permanent that was a creature until end of turn remain tapped after it stops being one?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a non-creature permanent turns into a creature until end of turn and attacks, does it remain tapped after it stops being one?

For example, if I activate [Sarkhan, the Dragonspeaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sarkhan%2C%20the%20Dragonspeaker)'s first ability, then attack with him, and then end my turn, will Sarkhan remain tapped when he stops being a dragon?

Comment: The technical term you're looking for is *tapped*, not "turned".

Comment: Thanks. I play cards on another language and couldn't remember the name of the term in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: Being tapped/untapped is a part of the *status* of a permanent and is independent of its type (creature/not creature) or other characteristic.

> 110.6. A permanent’s status is its physical state. There are four status categories, each of which has two possible values: tapped/untapped, flipped/unflipped, face up/face down, and phased in/phased out. Each permanent always has one of these values for each of these categories.
>
> 110.6a Status is not a characteristic, though it may affect a permanent’s characteristics.

In your example, Sarkhan, the Dragonspeaker will remain tapped even after your turn ends.